# fixed bootstrap panel on the right overlaps the form on left on screen resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

i have a form on left

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
```

and a panel on right

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="panel panel-primary" id="panel">
```

panel css

```
@media (min-width: 767px) { 
    #panel {
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: fixed;
        top: 25%;
    }
}
```

when you resize screen, the panel appears on the form

Comment: whats the question ?

Comment: Please recreate this issue in jsFiddle or Bootply, or provide more code. As it stands, we can't even see your issue or replicate it, so there's no way we can fix it.

Comment: @TimLewis thanks for taking your time you can see my answer it might better explain the problem i couldn't use bootply they don't allow minimized views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution, since i was using .col-md-

> Collapsed to start, horizontal above breakpoints Class prefix `.col-md-` is 970px

since my media query was `@media (min-width: 767px)` between 767px and 970px the penal was position: fixed; and not collapsed, so i edited to

```
  @media screen and (min-width: 970px) { 
        #panel{
             vertical-align: middle;
            position: fixed;
             top: 25%;
        }
    }
```

and everything is fine! thanks.